JHipster failed to upgrade from 8.1.0
My JHipster project was created on version 8.0.0 and then successfully upgraded to version 8.1.0.  After that, there is error when I try to upgrade to 8.2.1 or 8.3.0 with the following error.
   create src\test\java\com\pccw\hktms\mp\config\RedisTestContainersSpringContextCustomizerFactory.java
ERROR! ERROR! Error parsing file src\main\java\com\pccw\hktms\mp\config\SecurityConfiguration.java: Error: Sad sad panda, parsing errors detected in line: 42, column: 9!
Expecting --> ';' <-- but found --> 'return' <--!
        ->compilationUnit
        ->ordinaryCompilationUnit
        ->typeDeclaration
        ->classDeclaration
        ->normalClassDeclaration
        ->classBody
        ->classBodyDeclaration
        ->classMemberDeclaration
        ->methodDeclaration
        ->methodBody
        ->block
        ->blockStatements
        ->blockStatement
        ->statement
        ->statementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
        ->expressionStatement at package com.pccw.hktms.mp.config;

import com.pccw.hktms.mp.security.*;
import tech.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.servlet.util.matcher.MvcRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector;


@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    public SecurityConfiguration( JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {
        this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf
                .disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authz ->
                // prettier-ignore
                authz
                    .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/api/authenticate")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/api/admin/**")).hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/api/**")).authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/v3/api-docs/**")).hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/management/health")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/management/health/**")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/management/info")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/management/prometheus")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/management/**")).hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN))
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc(HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) {
        return new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
    }
}
    at file:///C:/Users/02007425/IdeaProjects/mp-api/node_modules/generator-jhipster/dist/generators/bootstrap/support/java-unused-imports-transform.mjs:20:27
    at Transform.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/02007425/IdeaProjects/mp-api/node_modules/@yeoman/transform/dist/transform.js:42:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Transform.transform [as _transform] (file:///C:/Users/02007425/IdeaProjects/mp-api/node_modules/@yeoman/transform/dist/transform.js:16:37)
ERROR! An error occured while running jhipster:upgrade#prepareUpgradeBranch
ERROR! ERROR! Command failed with exit code 1: npx --no jhipster --force --skip-install --skip-git --ignore-errors --no-insight --skip-checks
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npx --no jhipster --force --skip-install --skip-git --ignore-errors --no-insight --skip-checks
    at makeError (file:///C:/Program%20Files/nodejs/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:60:11)
    at handlePromise (file:///C:/Program%20Files/nodejs/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/execa/index.js:124:26)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async UpgradeGenerator.prepareUpgradeBranch (file:///C:/Program%20Files/nodejs/node_modules/generator-jhipster/dist/generators/upgrade/generator.js:168:21)
    at async UpgradeGenerator.executeTask (file:///C:/Program%20Files/nodejs/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/dist/actions/lifecycle.js:244:13)
    at async runLoop.add.once (file:///C:/Program%20Files/nodejs/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/dist/environment-base.js:395:17) {
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 1: npx --no jhipster --force --skip-install --skip-git --ignore-errors --no-insight --skip-checks',

Clearly, it is missing a ; at the end of the line .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/management/**")).hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)).
I've tried to update npm and node to the latest versions.  But the same problem still exists.
>npm doctor
Check                      Value   Recommendation/Notes
npm ping                   ok
npm -v                     ok      current: v10.5.2, latest: v10.5.2
node -v                    ok      current: v20.12.2, recommended: v20.12.2
npm config get registry    ok      using default registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/)
git executable in PATH     ok      C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE
global bin folder in PATH  ok      C:\Program Files\nodejs


There is no such problem when upgrading to version 8.5.0.
Maybe the problem has been fixed.

Please try the JHipster Migrate blueprint and see if it works for you:
npm install -g generator-jhipster-migrate
jhipster-migrate

